# iphone to ipad porting

Tags: iphone, ipad, porting

i have iphone project based on tabbar template . want to convert it to ipad, 
final output i want is to move tabbar inside a splitviewcontroller .

How to go about?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite it to be in correspondence with the change in templates... There is no other way sorry to be the bearer of bad news. But, you can still potentially re-use a lot of the variables and IBOutlets and IBActions that you had from the previous project. You just have to take that code and fix it so it works with the new template.

Answer (score 0):

I recently found this blog post on the topic. You might find it helpful:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

Plus there's some discussion of creating a universal app here:

[iPhone & iPad versions of same app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615463/iphone-ipad-versions-of-same-app)