# Convert iPad application to iPhone application?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have written a tab based iPad application which has done well. I never intended for it to be an iPhone application because the content it displays really doesnt lend itself to such a small screen.

However, I have been getting a lot of requestes for the application to be compatible with iPhones as well.

Can someone point me in the direction of some documentation that may help me figure out how to convert my app.

I presume it's not so simple as having aanother set of XIB files for iPhone and just have it display them if the app is running on a phone...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently found this blog post on the topic. You might find it helpful:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

Plus there's some discussion of creating a universal app here:

[iPhone & iPad versions of same app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615463/iphone-ipad-versions-of-same-app)

Answer (score 3):

[iPad Programming Guide: Creating a Universal Application](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html)

Comment: That's somewhat helpful, but some things are glossed over - such as "If your view controller uses nib files, you must specify different nib files for each device type when creating the view controller." --- how do I do that?