# Convert ipad application to iphone. Universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, universal-binary

Convert iPad application to iPhone- Universal app.

I already have one iPad application, now I want to make a universal app of that iPad application.

How to convert? Is it possible? Or do I have to start a new app?

Comment: It will not convert it self. :) You need to start development. Grab the code/project of iPad application, study it. Implement it according to iPhone design...

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPad to iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058459/ipad-to-iphone)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open up your project in Interface Builder. Click on the disclosure triangle next to "Targets", then right-click on the target and choose "Upgrade Current Target for iPad...".

Then read the [iPad Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), especially the section [Starting Your Project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/StartingYourProject/StartingYourProject.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009370-CH9-SW1).

Edit:

I see now -- iPad to iPad/iPhone.

I think you would do something like the following:

1. Create a .xib for the iPhone for the
   Main Window/App Delegate/etc, to
   corresspond your existing .xib for
   iPad.
2. Add an entry in your info plist:
   `NSMainNibFile`, with the value of the
   name of your new iPhone xib
3. Go to your build settings and set
   the Base SDK to 4.1 (or 4.0 if you
   still have the older SDK installed)
4. Keep your iOS Deployment Target
   build setting at 3.2 if you're only
   worried about iPhones and iPod
   Touches with 4.x.
5. Set the Targeted Device Family build
   setting to iPhone/iPad
6. Start refactoring your code to
   create two different code paths, one
   for iPhone and one for iPad, where
   appropriate.

Comment: Actually, it's about iPad to iPad/iPhone. But I misread it, too; I just saw the Universal App bit.

Comment: Ah, right. Please consider voting to close as duplicate too and if it gets closed flag for moderator attention to merge this answer into the duplicate (sadly there are currently just link-only answers).