# change universal application to ipad 3.2 application

Tags: ipad, universal

i am creating an universal application now i want to change that application into ipad 3.2 application.How can i do that.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the exact opposite of [Convert ipad application to iphone. Universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675858/convert-ipad-application-to-iphone-universal-app/3682995#3682995)

- Remove the .xib created for the iPhone (contains the Main Window/App Delegate/etc.)
- Remove the `NSMainNibFile~ipad` entry from your Info.plist file
- Change the Base SDK setting from 4.x to 3.2
- Change your Deployment Target setting to 3.2
- Set the Targeted Device Family build setting to iPad (from iPhone/iPad)
- Remove any code you've created to make an iPhone-specific code path