# change ipad applications to iphone applications

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert ipad application to iphone. Universal app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675858/convert-ipad-application-to-iphone-universal-app)

I created one application which is iPad application. I want to change this iPad applications to iPhone applications.For that I change my application in universal. But the size of images,buttons etc are the same. Can I change my application to iPhone app? How can I do that? Or Is it necessary to create another application for iPhone? Can you give a solution for that? Please help me?

Comment: Please Goes Through the Below Link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675858/convert-ipad-application-to-iphone-universal-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another target from the first one (right click on the existing target and duplicate).
Concerning the frames of your views (label, buttons, etc...), it will depend of the way you've created them. If you've sized and placed them regarding the size of the screen, it should be ok.

Concerning your images, the best is to re-design them specially for the iphone target