# Convert iPad app to iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, universal

Ive created an iPad app which we are due to send to the app store at the start of next month for approval. The boss has queried me to see whether it could also run on the iphone.I know it is quite easy to convert your app to be universal (compatible for iphone and iPad) but being all the views are designed for the ipad screen size its gonna be the process of chopping and changing to suit the smaller screen size of the iPhone.

Can anybody think of anyway i can make our iPad designed app suitable for the iPhone in a short amount of time? (if there is a way i can fit the big ipad views on the iPhone screen in some manner but still keeping the apple reviewers happy)

Comment: This has been asked several times before, for example: [iPad to iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058459/ipad-to-iphone).

Answer (score 1):

There's no shortcut here - you'll have to redesign the views to fit on a smaller resolution screen, and then create a separate App Delegate and select correct XIBs at runtime.

Comment: You don't need to create a separate app delegate to select the correct XIBs at runtime.  The app can select via a runtime check of the app's UI paradigm.  The rest of your answer, I agree with.