# iPhone: IB, switching between iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone

I have a project. When I choose some xib file, iPhone simulator shows in IB. Is there any whey to change it to iPad simulator ? Thanks in advance...

Comment: is your project for ipad only or is it universal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you begin your app, you will be asked for its platform, eg. iphone or ipad or Universal. Select Universal. This will give you three delegates for your project.

> YourAppDelegate
>
> YourAppDelegate_iPad
>
> YourAppDelegate_iPhone

Now for ipad, when you add a nib, do not forget to checkmark "Targeted For Ipad".
Then in the file YourAppDelegate_ipad.m file,

```
     // In YourAppDelegate_iPad.m
     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:           (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
     {
         NSLog(@"iPad App Delegate");
         //insert your controller over here with the specified xib fileName...
         return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about simulator but for device i think there is a good option called universal app.

and i think my question [Convert iPad application to iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855001/convert-ipad-application-to-iphone) should help you more ..

this log can help you to convert iphone app to ipad

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad

Answer (score 0):

iPhone and iPad user interface are defined in different XIB files. When you create a new XIB, Xcode asks you whether it's for the iPad or iPhone/iPod touch.

Go on, create a new XIB (choose a template containing only a window or view) and you'll see.

(Of course, there are many more steps to perform before it actually works. Read articles about universal apps to know more.)