# Convert iPad xib to iPhone xib

Tags: iphone, ipad, xib

I have seen many posts and tutorials about converting iPhone xibs to iPad xibs, but I want to do it the other way around.

The only resource I've been able to find is this :
[Convert iPad application to iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855001/convert-ipad-application-to-iphone)

And it only covers compilation and code deviation. I know about the ~ipad / ~iphone xib postfix trick, but would like to get a head start on generating the iPhone xib, so that I don't have to create it from scratch, but can start with an automatically modified version of the original xib and work from there.

I have seen tools that do this the other way around (iPad xib from iPhone xib), but that is not what I'm looking for.
Does anyone know of such a tool, or of a manual way to get this head start?

(Main issue would be resizing elements to fit in their relative position in the lower resolution)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and past the xib file and rename it with "nameXib_iPad.xib".
In this way your object are linked with the original class.
Now you must change the code of nib name and switch iPone - iPad.

have you tried to do it?

Comment: This doesn't help in the porting process (the resolutions are different, and the iPhone->iPad direction has tools that assist in auto-resizing and such, I was looking for the other way around)

Comment: you must resize the xib, choose the view from the xib and set freeform  from the property

Comment: Will this automatically resize all of its child elements?

Comment: NO, you must resize all object. The best way to do an universal app is create the object with code without xib.

Answer (score 0):

you can use constraints to make the xib file compatible with iPhone an iPad.