# convert ipad xib to iphone xib in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, xcode4, xib

I am trying to find out, how to convert iPad xib to iPhone xib. 
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900427/convert-ipad-xib-to-iphone-xib) which sais in one of the answers:

```
     "Now you must change the code of nib name and switch iPhone - iPad"
```

I don't understand how to do that. And I think it might be important, because in my UIView, Simulated Matrix, Size, I have the option "iPad full screen", and I would like to use "iPhone full screen"

Thanks, Shefy

Comment: I am not sure wht u are trying to do but you can just remove the base view of xib and add a new UIView with the desired size add this as the base view of the xib.

Comment: 10x for you response. Because the code of the class is complex, and the whole project I'm basing my work on was written by another developer, and I have many other xib I will need to convert - I have to use the same xibs to save in the development time.

Comment: so you mean to say you liked my comment..? Should I post this as an answer...?

Comment: Sure, not answering my specific problem, but might help others.

Comment: This guy recommends something similar which you want achieve.. you can have a look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7285231/919545

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but you can just remove the base view of xib and add a new UIView with the desired size add this as the base view of the xib